# Purpose of input resistor in ADC circuit

Tags: resistors, adc

What is the implication of the 1 Megaohm resistor in the schematics attached? Will I be able to detect the condition of the motor (running, not running, stalled)?

Part information:

- MCU ADC (ADC type: SAR) leakage current is 1uA.
- R3 (Load) is a H bridge (pair of PNPs (5CS) and NPNs(6CS)).
- Motor type is DC brush-less with following current rating:
  Normal Load Current (Running) - 80 mA
  Stall Current - 200 mA

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9qaV1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It serves no purpose without knowing the ADC type.

Comment: The ADC type is Successive Approximation Type

Comment: That is the topology - I'm wanting to know the part number.

Comment: The ADC is built in the Micro controller. The Micro controller part number is R5F10WLFAFA. Link Here: http://www.renesas.com/req/product_document_lineup_child.do?REGION_KEY=1&LAYER_KEY=85282&PDF_URL=http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/rl78/r01uh0382ej0200_rl78l13.pdf&TKUPDATE=true&APNOTE=true&AUTHORFLG=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1M resistor would allow high voltage spikes to exist at the motor without damaging the ADC input. By limiting the current into the ADC input protection network, even a 1kV spike would be rendered harmless (unless the resistor arced over).

However most ADC inputs are not very tolerant of such a high input resistance unless they have a built in buffer amplifier- often a few K ohms is the maximum recommended. Even if there is a buffer (rare) the datasheet leakage spec (you say 1uA) is usually too high to guarantee reasonable accuracy (*typical* leakage might be pA at room temperature if buffered). So, the design seems somewhat dubious at first blush, though it may indeed function. It's doubtful actual spikes exceeding a few tens of volts would occur at the power to an H-bridge, so a resistor value of a few K might be fine.

The diode is presumably to prevent the current sense resistor from limiting the motor stall/start current. It will kick in at around 270mA motor current. If the motor is 'plugged' it's quite possible to get around double the stall current momentarily.

Comment: The H Bridge is not operated at fast rate. the motor will turn in one direction for some time (ot stall happens whichever is earlier) and then moves back. this typically takes 10 seconds. So, correct me if i am wrong, shall i assume that the voltage across the H bridge at maximum will be at best, 10-15 V for short period.

Comment: @KumarGR most likely, especially if there is a capacitor across the H-bridge power.

Comment: yes there is one 100 uF capacitor between H bridge power and ground. Also there is one 100 nF in parallel to the Motor. what is the implication? Thanks

Comment: If the 100uF is across R3 then any spikes will be greatly attenuated.

Comment: @Sphero Only the 100 nF is across the Motor. The 100 uF capacitor is across the main Battery supply. The purpose of the diode that you have assumed is much convincing for me

Comment: @Sphero The forward drop of the diode is 0.17 V when measured using multimeter in DIODE mode. This brings down the Kick in current to 77 mA. Will I be able to detect STALL current now?

Comment: Your multimeter is wrong (or you've left the resistor in place! and/or it's a Schottky). **Assuming it's really a 1N4148**, error should be less than 5% even at 300mA and 85°C Ta.

Comment: Kindly forgive me. The diode part in the picture is my ignorance. I removed the diode from PCB and then measured the drop.

Comment: @KumarGR What part number is it, and what current does your multimeter measure at? If it's a 1N4148 then drop is high. If it's a Schottky drop will be much less. It actually makes more sense that it would be a Schottky- then you could likely measure run current but not stall current accurately.

Comment: @Sphero Sorry to say that I do not have the part number but only physical sample on the board. Th multimeter is Fluke and I can say that current is only 100 nA or less while measuring forward voltage drop.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that the author of this schematic fragment intended the 1M resistor to be representative of the ADC's input impedance, rather than a physical component. In that case, the resistor is not a discrete part you add, but aids calculating things such as how much the ADC affects the voltage at that node.

If it was intended as a physical component, it's a bad idea. The ADC already has a high input impedance - as indicated by the 1uA leakage you quoted - and a large series impedance will create error in the ADC. The node that the 1Mohm resistor is connected to is very low impedance in any case, so it's not necessary to add a series resistor here.

Comment: R2 is indeed a physical component. is it possible to expalin a little more about error? the ADC is 10 bit, with overall error of 8 bit. For this application, as i need to sense stall current and running current, i can make safe assumption that 3% or even 5% error should be acceptable. sampling frequency is also low (<1 kHz)

Comment: 1 microamp leakage current from the ADC will produce a voltage drop of 1 volt across R2 - a huge error relative to whatever you're trying to measure. R2 here serves no purpose, and only adds error to your measurements.

Comment: Also, the configuration of D1 and R1 is very odd. I can only assume D1 is intended to be for kickback protection for the motor, but if so it's in the wrong place, and instead serves to limit the voltage across R1, giving incorrect current measurements if the voltage drop is more than the diode's forward voltage.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the drop across R2. I am not protesting but the section i have shared is from a fully working design for the specific purpose i mentioned in the schematics above. Even the diode, i still not have got the purpose. I am 100% sure about schematics. Why would one use such a high resistor? H Bridge has no diodes for protection! too other than one big 100 uF capacitor between 3V and ground.

Comment: I don't know - without seeing the rest of the schematic it's impossible to say, but I can't see any good reason for R2 whatsoever.